# Magento ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: magento2

I have Magento working in a cPanel, but I need to migrate in to Docker.

I kept the same version of PHP (7.1.33) and also MySQL (5.7).

Installed the extensions:

```
mysqli, pdo_mysql, mcrypt, intl, xsl, gd, bcmath, soap, zip, sockets, sqlsrv, pdo_sqlsrv.
```

Run the commands:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

However when I try to access the page I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and Apache consumes all the resources of the machine. 8GB RAM & 8 threads.

Magento version 2.2.6.
Where dit I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Enable all `Cache` and see if that helps. `bin/magento cache:enable`

Comment: Thanks for help, but some problem ```www-data@f4d1da4e2e84:~/html$ php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:enable
Killed```

Comment: Looks like you have memory limit, try editing the config file directly and save it. File: `app/etc/env.php`, make `cache_types` all to `1`.

Comment: The memory limit is the RAM limit ```Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)```